# Merge two regexp in single one php

Tags: php, regex

I need to know if there is any way to  merge two regular expression into a single regexp. Recently I had to make the following php code but I feel that there is a simplified way to achieve this without using *multiple preg_replace* tags. What I am trying to do is strip off `&nbsp; &amp; &copy;` etc.. and to remove all multiple spaces

```
$textinput = 'this is a test input       \'     """"""    """" @#$$%&*)_+!@#$%^&*)   123    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;456';

$var = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i",'',$textinput)
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $var);
```

### output

```
this is a test input ' """""""""" @#$$%&*)_+!@#$%^&*) 123 456
```

**I am aware about the `html_entity_decode` function in php to strip the special characters off, well this just an example!** How can I merge both of the regexp into a single one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do your two replacements in one efficient step (without losing the whitespace character):

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~(?:&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};)+|\s\K\s+~', '', $yourstring);
```

On [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/23), see how all the extra characters are targeted.

**Explanation**

- On the left side of the `|`, `(?:&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};)+` targets groups such as `&nbsp;`, not just one at a time but several together if they are touching.
- On the right side, the `\s` matches one space, then the `\K` tells the engine to drop it from the match (it will not be replaced), then the `\s+` matches any whitespace chars that follow
- We replace with the empty string.

Comment: FYI: Added demo and explanation. :)

Comment: @anubhava Thx! Started out with a `(?<=\s)` then remembered it's PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a logical OR operator to combine both regexes,

```
(?:&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};)+|(?<=\s)\s+
```

Your code would be,

```
<?php
$mystring = 'this is a test input       \'     """"""    """" @#$$%&*)_+!@#$%^&*)   123    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;456';
$pattern = "~(?:&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};)+|(?<=\s)\s+~";
$replacement = "";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $mystring);
?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php
$mystring = 'this is a test input       \'     """"""    """" @#$$%&*)_+!@#$%^&*)   123    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;456';
$pattern = "~&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};|(?<=\s)\s+~";
$replacement = "";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $mystring);
?>
```

output:

```
this is a test input ' """""" """" @#$$%&*)_+!@#$%^&*) 123 456
```

Comment: thanks for your comments. I had already tried that. But this is the output I am getting after using the regexp you have suggested me `this is a test input ' """""""""" @#$$%&*)_+!@#$%^&*) 123       456`! see the multiple spaces in place of special chars. Any other way?

Comment: thanks for the edit. Still there is a slight mistake in it. The output should be `this is a test input ' """""""""" @#$$%&*)_+!@#$%^&*) 123 456` see the space you are missing in between **)** and **123**.

Answer (score 2):

```
$var = preg_replace_callback('/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};|\s+/i', function($match) {
    return $match[0][0] === '&' ? '' : ' ';
}, $textinput);
```

Comment: No problem @zx81's solution looks pretty handy too. You can also just use `preg_replace` with arrays as the args